# Use Visual Studio Code in vb.net project as main editor

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-code

I am searching but nothing found about the my question.

I have a vb.net project with inside ScintillaNet as editor.
My project consists of an SQL script repository stored in MSSQL, organized with a title, a category, tags and so on. I deploy a simple interface for users, so they can run my select just with a click.
To edit the script I am using ScintillaNET as part of my project.

My question: is there a way to import VS Code in my vb.net project to replace scintillaNet?

Comment: VS Code is a very complex program, and it isn't written in a .NET language. It is probably possible to use its editor in .NET, but I don't think it'll be easy to implement.

Comment: thanks for your reply and sorry for delay.